# Changing the name of Moderators SE: the saga continues

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, site-name

I'm Pops, one of the Community Managers at Stack Exchange. A little while ago, the team got together to talk about [your request for a change of this site's name](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/should-we-change-our-name-redux).

What we've heard from you is that you don't like the name "Moderators" for a few reasons:

- when outsiders hear "Moderators Stack Exchange," they assume what you do here is the kind of stuff that actually happens on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and other meta sites
- the scope of this site is broader than just moderation; in other words, moderation is just a subset of what's on-topic here
- issues relating to "real-world"/non-digital communities are on-topic here, and "moderator" might not even be the proper term to use for the people involved in the moderator-like role
- even just when talking about moderation, more people than moderators should be involved (i.e. the users here should be drawn from a wider pool than just people who are moderators of other sites/groups/communities)
- the current name might be affecting the amount of traffic you're getting
- [your consensus choice](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/177/7) for a new name is "Communities Stack Exchange"

Generally, we agree with all of the points you made. Our only concern is that "Communities SE" might be a bit too broad/vague to paint a good picture of what the site is actually about. Out of the options that came up in the meta discussion, ["Community Building SE"](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/7) is our favorite. It should cover all the bases you want to cover, while still giving people some sense of what aspect of communities you're dealing with (as opposed to, say, the kinds of things that might be covered over at [Travel SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com)).

If you guys like "Community Building" as a name, we can flip the switch on that pretty quickly. Alternatively, you're welcome to try to come up with a third option. So here's the actual question: are you okay with this site being Community Building SE? If not, what do you want instead?

Comment: I would have preferred Communities but I can go along with Community Building.  Thanks for working with us on this!

Answer (score 13):

I think community building works fine.  I can't think of anything better.

Comment: This was your chance to suggest "Batman Stack Exchange"...

Comment: @Shog9 - but everyone already knows my real identity, I can't very well start a secret one now.

Comment: @Shog9 That wouldn't be cricket.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like Community Building Stack Exchange is the winner! It'll take a little while to push this change through, because the site's "real" name has a lot of dependencies internally, but I promise it is coming.

Edit: aaaaand done! Enjoy!

Comment: Yay!  Thanks Pops!  ([meta-tag:status-completed]?)

Comment: So statussed, @MonicaCellio.